# Realizing a matrix of equations: Using a loop to define functions (Python)

Tags: python, function, iteration

For context, I am essentially using a numerical integrator that takes in a set of differential equations defined as functions. A large set of these functions follow a regular pattern and I would like to define them in a loop (or whatever is the most suitable way). For example;

```
#system coordinates
s = [y1,y2]

#system equations
def e1(s):
    x1 = s[1]**2 + 1
    return x1

def e2(s):
    x1 = s[2]**2 + 2
    return x1

#equations of motion
eom = [e1,e2]
```

Not all of the functions will follow the exact pattern, for those that do though ideally I need something like,

```
def en(s)
    x1 = s[n]**2 + n
    return x1
```

where it is possible to iterate over a range of 'n' values. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply use a second parameter in your function like so:

```
def en(s, n)
    x1 = s[n]**2 + n
    return x1

result = []
for i in range(100):  # 100 is just for illustration purposes..
    result[0] = en(s, i)  # you do not have to store them in a list. just an example
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am currently trying, the problem is now storing these equations with those that do not follow the pattern, eg. `eom = [e0,e1,e2]` is the list I'm calling equations from as it stands, and `e0` is different from the others.

Comment: you only need one equation with more parameters, not 100 equations with one parameter each.

Comment: you can even decouple the index from the value you are adding like `x1 = s[n]**2 + a` with `a` being a third parameter passed to the `en` function

Answer (score 0):

I would use `partial`, wich bind values to functions arguments:

```
import functools

def e1(s, n, v1, v2):
    x1 = s[n]**v1 + v2
    return x1

[functools.partial(e1, n=i, v1=2, v2=1) for i in range(10)] # this was your first example

#your second example
[functools.partial(e1, n=n, v1=2, v2=n) for n in range(10)]
```

Comment: `partial` is an overkill for this example imho

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, as he shows in the example `eom = [e1,e2]` he wants a list of callables, not a list of values, your answer is not what he is searching. So actually `partial` is the way to go

Comment: This is an XY problem. With all due respect, he thinks he does, he does not. It does not make sense to require many different callables that all do the same thing.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, im not getting into his mind, this is not about guessing what he needs but to answer his question in my opinion. Of course, to abstract the function and call it with the proper arguments is the easy way for it, but I dont know if he needs the callable for someting, so, he ask for callables, I provide him how to create them. Overkill or not.